# How to "group by" over list elements (in Base R)

Tags: r, list, aggregate

Code

```
list(c(1,2), c('a', 'b'), c('a', 'b'), c(2,3)) -> li
## 
## [[1]]
## [1] 1 2
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "a" "b"
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] "a" "b"
## 
## [[4]]
## [1] 2 3
```

Q: Required output as from table().

```
Factor     c(1,2) c('a', 'b') c(2,3)
Freq           1        2        1
```

It looks very elementary, but I cannot find a solution.

**Edit** - Unfortunately, my list contains ca 500,000 elements. Sorry for not mentioning that. A solution might be to merge the items in the list into a single element:

```
## 
## [[1]]
## [1] "1 2"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "a b"
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] "a b"
## 
## [[4]]
## [1] "2 3"
```

Then unlist the list and apply table.

Q: How to concatenate the list elements in a single item?

A: `sapply(li, paste, collapse = "-") |> table()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`unique` and `match` work with lists, so you can `match` your list to `unique` members of itself. Call `table` on the result, then all than remains is to set the names of the result using `unique` again. This can all be done with the one-liner:

```r
setNames(table(match(li, unique(li))), unique(li))
#>    c(1, 2) c("a", "b")     c(2, 3) 
#>          1           2           1
```

Or, if you prefer clarity to brevity, the base R piped equivalent would be:

```r
li |>
  match(unique(li))    |>
  table()              |>
  setNames(unique(li))
#>    c(1, 2) c("a", "b")     c(2, 3) 
#>          1           2           1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could extract the unique elements, than count how often an element of the list is inside the list of unique elements:

```
# All unique list elements
uniques = li[!duplicated(li)]

# How many list elements are inside the list containing a single unique element, for each unique element
freq = lapply(uniques, function(x) length(which(li %in% list(x))))

# Set the unique elements as names
names(freq) = uniques

freq
# $`c(1, 2)`
# [1] 1
# 
# $`c("a", "b")`
# [1] 2
# 
# $`c(2, 3)`
# [1] 1
```

Comment: Ah, that's the same method @Allan Cameron posted in his answer... But his solution is nicer :)